# How To Get External Page Title Tag Text Of A Link Using Pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, get, title, var

I am trying to do one thing. I have a external link on my test page and I want to get the title tag of that external link page that will be like `<title>Desired Title Tag</title>` in a variable on my test page through pure JavaScript only. Can I do it? Do you have the code? Can you do it?

Comment: In most situations no, unless the remote page is also on your own domain. If not you can hope that [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is allowed, or use something like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Or see if the remote page(s) has, or have, an API of some kind.

Comment: @DavidThomas Ok, So if the external link page is also on my domain then can I do it. Like can I get my site other page title tag using their link only?